# Guess a number with two players - game doesn't stop when it should

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a prototype of "two players guess a number", but it doesn't stop when `points == 5`. It ends when the player is the winner the tenth time.
Anybody knows what is wrong?

```
def play_game():
    p1 = 0
    p2 = 0
    shots_taken = 0

    number = int(input("Graczu pierwszy - wprowadź liczbę od 1 do 20: "))
    while number < 1 or number > 20:
        number = int(input("Zła liczba, podaj prawidłową: "))
    while shots_taken < 3:
        shot = int(input("Graczu drugi - zgadnij: "))
        shots_taken += 1
        if shot < number:
            print("Więcej")
        if shot > number:
            print("Mniej")
        if shot == number:
            break


    if shot != number:
        print("Gracz pierwszy wygrywa.")
        p1 += 1
    else:
        print("Gracz drugi wygrywa.")
        p2 += 1
    return [p1, p2]

points = [0, 0]

while points[0] < 5 or points[1] < 5:
    points = [0, 0]
    points[0] += play_game()[0]
    points[1] += play_game()[1]
    if points[0] == 5 or points[1] == 5:
        break

print("Gracz 1 ma punktów", points[0])
print("Gracz 2 ma punktów", points[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

You reset the score back to 0:0 at the beginning of each loop:

```
points = [0, 0]

while points[0] < 5 or points[1] < 5:
    # points = [0, 0]  <-- Remove this line
    points[0] += play_game()[0]
    points[1] += play_game()[1]
    if points[0] == 5 or points[1] == 5:
        break
```

Additionally, you run two games in each loop.
Try:

```
points = [0, 0]

while points[0] < 5 or points[1] < 5:
    result = play_game() # Result will have the format [x, y]
    points[0] += result[0]
    points[1] += result[1]
    if points[0] == 5 or points[1] == 5:
        break
```